# Supressing System Dialog when pairing Bluetooth devices using Win 7 or Win 10

Tags: .net, bluetooth

I am successfully automatically pairing Bluetooth device against Win 7 and Win 10, using feet32 Library. Unfortunately a System Dialog shows up, saying "tap to pair" Under Win 7 it pairs if I Tap the Dialog or not. Under Win 10 it does not pair, if I do not touch the dialog.
Actually, there is a Win 10 option, that switches off the dialog, but then no pairing takes place also. 
Under Win 7 handlerequests is called, under Win 10 it is not.

Under Win 7 it pairs anyway.

[image: This is the win 7 Dialog]

[image: This is the Win 10 Dialog]

```
Dim  pairer As New BluetoothWin32Authentication(AddressOf handleRequests ) 

Public Sub handleRequests(ByVal thing As Object, ByVal args As BluetoothWin32AuthenticationEventArgs)        
    args.Confirm = True
End Sub

Protected Function TryRemember(ByVal peer As BluetoothDeviceInfo) As Boolean
    If peer Is Nothing Then Return False        
    Return BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(peer.DeviceAddress, Nothing )
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to do that. However our Bluetooth Framework can do that by using undocumented way. Works on any Windows platform.

I can not share the code but I can give you the idea. You have to disable Authentication Agent.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Can I do that within feet32 or against the WinAPI directly, or in your Bluetooth Framework, As far as your Frameowork is concerned, is it publically avalable, or very closed?

Comment: You have to use WinAPI. Please, contact me by skype and I'll provide a code (sorry, but only for YOUR PERSONAL use).

Comment: Forgot to give you a skype ID: mike.petrichenko