# ble pairing without bluetooth control panel

Tags: wpf, windows, bluetooth

I want to pair a ble device without windows UI bluetooth pairing dialog. I am using that code but still windows UI interrupts and asks for pin code again

With aw there is a popup window asking user to input PINcode on the device.
but  after entering pincode and closed the popup immediately windows UI notification comes up  and asks to pair the device again which I don't want.

```
private void CustomOnPairingRequested(DeviceInformationCustomPairing sender, DevicePairingRequestedEventArgs args)

        {

            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                this.prgbar.Value = 32;
                aw.Closing += (object sendera, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) =>
                 {
                     args.Accept(aw.pincode_text);
                 };
                aw.Show();
```

There is a mention to disable auth manager but I can find out how

> I can not share the code but I can give you the idea. You have to
> disable Authentication Agent.

[Supressing System Dialog when pairing Bluetooth devices using Win 7 or Win 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469499/supressing-system-dialog-when-pairing-bluetooth-devices-using-win-7-or-win-10/49473916#49473916)